# Delete query with sparql

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, fuseki

I am trying to delete some triples using this query but it gives me following error

> this line is invalid

I don't get what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me?

```
DELETE DATA{ 
GRAPH <http://vitali.web.cs.unibo.it/raschietto/graph/ltw1536>
            { [ a   oa:Annotation;
                   rdfs:label "Author"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> ;
                   vurp:type "hasAuthor"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#normalizedString> ;
                   oa:AnnotatedAt "2015-8-26T10:1:25"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime>;
                    oa:AnnotatedBy <ccc>;

                oa:hasBody [ a rdf:Statement;
                    rdf:object [ a <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person> ;
                    rdf:subject  <http://vitali.web.cs.unibo.it/raschietto/person/s-undefinedstocazzo> ;  
                    rdfs:label "stocazzo"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>                 
                    ];

            rdf:predicate <http://purl.org/dc/terms/creator> ;      
            rdf:subject <http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/knoth/11knoth.html> ; 
            rdfs:label "An author of the document is stocazzo"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>

          ] ;
              oa:hasTarget [ a  oa:SpecificResource;
                                          oa:hasSelector [a oa:FragmentSelector;
                                                            rdf:value "form1_table3_tbody1_tr1_td1_table5_tbody1_tr1_td1_table1_tbody1_tr1_td2_p4"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#normalizedString>;
                                                            oa:end "91"^^<xsd:nonNegativeInteger>;
                                                            oa:start "77"^^<xsd:nonNegativeInteger>
                                                            ];
                                                     oa:hasSource <http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/knoth/11knoth.html>;
                                                        ]
            ].
                                       }
                }
```

Comment: **'this line is invalid"** It doesn't say anything about *which* line?  Are you creating this query in code?  Are you including newlines?  If you do, then your query would be on multiples lines, and you might get a line number.  If you don't, then it's all just one line.  It's easy to make mistakes in string concatenation, too, e.g., `"select ?x" + "where {"` becomes `select ?xwhere {` which will be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what the specific error you're getting it, but if you paste your query into the [validator at sparql.org](http://sparql.org/validate/update), there's at least one problem that is surely significant, and could be your issue:

> Line 10, column 15: Blank nodes not allowed in DELETE templates

Comment: It gives me an error on line "{ [ a   oa:Annotation; " and if i change that it keeps giving me error like that: Encountered "  "\"Comment\" "" at line 25, column 17.
Was expecting one of:
    "}" ...
    ";" ...
    "," ...
    "." ...

Comment: @user3468308 Yes;  according to the validator, blank nodes aren't allowed in DELETE updates, and `[` is the beginning of a blank node.  Without seeing your actual Java code that's constructing the query, the line numbers and other quoted stuff like `Encountered " "\"Comment\" "" at line 25, column 17.` don't really mean anything to us.